# Why is this gigabit switch full duplex in gigabit mode, but only half duplex in 10/100 modes?

Tags: switch, gigabit-ethernet

According to the specs of the [D-Link DGS-1100-16 Easysmart 16-Port Gigabit Switch](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/business-solutions/support/product/dgs-1100-16-16-port-10-100-1000-easysmart-switch) at [amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SUO0YK):

> IEEE 802.3 compliant IEEE 802.3u compliant; Supports half/full-duplex operation (**half at 10/100 Mbps, full at 1000 Mbps**) Auto-negotiation; Auto MDI/MDIX; IEEE 802.3x Flow Control supports Full-Duplex mode; IEEE 802.3az compliant *[emphasis added]*

Why is it that a switch would support full duplex operation at 1000 Mbps, but not at the lower speeds?  It seems that it would be easier/cheaper/more logical to support FD at lower speeds than at high speeds.  So if they're going to the effort of making the switch FD at high speeds, why not at lower speeds, too?  What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it is just bad writing. Ignoring the switch  and consider that there is only full and half duplex 10mbit, full and half duplex 100mbit, and only full duplex Gb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad description on the page, Per page 35 in the [manual for the switch](ftp://ftp.dlink.es/Diagrams/Misc/DGS-1100%20Series_A1_Manual_v1.00%28WW%29.pdf) ([it's an anonymous login](http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/UNIXhelp1.3/Pages/tasks/ftp2.4.2.1.1.html)) the device support Half and Full duplex at 10/100 but only Full duplex at 1000.

> Port Functions 
>   10/100/1000BaseTX ports compliant with the following standards:
>   - IEEE 802.3
>   - IEEE 802.3u
>   - IEEE 802.3ab
>   - Supports Full/half-Duplex operations at 10/100Mbps
>   - Supports Full-Duplex operation at 1000Mbps

As @plugwash points out, half duplex gigabit is possible. But [almost] no such device exists. You will not run into in regular real world setups.

Comment: Ah-ha! Good find. I suppose finding a half-duplex gigabit card would be pretty hard anyway.

Comment: It has been a while since I read the standards, but if my memory serves then no half-duplex gigabit exists. Gigabit networking is always full duplex.

Comment: @Hennes If you read between the lines I think it pretty much says that in the description of Gigabit technology on the page right before the one I used to provide the answer. `Gigabit Ethernet is an extension of IEEE 802.3 Ethernet utilizing the same packet structure, format, and support for CSMA/CD protocol, full duplex, and management objects...`

Comment: @Hennes half duplex gigabit exists in principle, however it is hardly ever used because gigabit hubs are like hens teeth (theres a spec for them but I never heard of anyone actually selling them). Therefore it is not surprising that some manufacturers don't bother to support it.

Comment: Ah, good to learn. I'll add that to the answer.